# Count number if integers in equation with php

Tags: php

I have the need to count the number of integers which i am adding/substracting from equation.
Lets say I have a switch statement like that:

```html
switch($_POST['dni']){
        case 2:
            $sum1 = $day1;
            $sum2 = $day2;
            break;
        case 3:
            $sum1 = $day1 + $day2;
            $sum2 = $day3;
            break;
        case 4:
            $sum1 = $day1 + $day2;
            $sum2 = $day3 + $day4;
            break;
        case 5:
            $sum1 = $day1 + $day2 + $day3;
            $sum2 = $day4 + $day5;
            break;
        case 6:
            $sum1 = $day1 + $day2 + $day3;
            $sum2 = $day4 + $day5 + $day6;
            break;
        case 7:
            $sum1 = $day1 + $day2 + $day3 + $day4;
            $sum2 = $day5 + $day6 + $day7;
            break;
        case 8:
            $sum1 = $day1 + $day2 + $day3 + $day4;
            $sum2 = $day5 + $day6 + $day7 + $day8;
            break;
```

And I have selected `$_POST['dni']` to be 7, can I count the number of integers in $sum1 equation?

The things I have tried so far:

- explode($sum1, '+') - returns the sum of the equation in array...
- count($sum1) - returns 1, because it is counting again the sum of
  equation...

Comment: It'd be helpful if you included the values of the variables used in your code, otherwise we'll be guessing.

Comment: The explode idea isn't bad, you just should set sum1 to be a string of that equation, not the actual result of the equation.

Comment: Thanks! Anthony's way works too, I am too dumb sometimes, thought its a string, but now i used var_dump  on $sum1 and it was int, lol.Both ways your and Joseph's works, Thank you guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you thinking of something like this?  But without a better example this is all I got for you.

```
$day1 = 1;
$day2 = 2;
$day3 = 3;
$day4 = 4;

$array = array(

'0' => $day1,
'1' => $day2,
'2' => $day3,
'3' => $day4

);

$sum = array_sum($array);

echo 'Sum: = ' . $sum . '<br>';  //Outputs 10
echo '# of Integers: = ' . count($array); //Outputs 4
```

Answer (score 0):

So I think it's a bad practice to use switch statement and re-did your code by -infer- method and resolved the issue, I hope it helps:

```
<?php

// In my example I have to declare the days and sums variables
// but I'm assuming you have them declared in your code already…

$dni  = 8; // Or $_POST['dni'];
$day1 = 3;
$day2 = 4;
$day3 = 6;
$day4 = 8;
$day5 = 2;
$day6 = 5;
$day7 = 3;
$day8 = 10;
$day9 = 15;

$sum1 = $sum2 = 0;

// Here by what I saw in your code, can be simplified with basic arithmetic.
// First I divide $dni by 2, if it's an odd number it'll result in a float number.
// By using ceil we round it to the closest even number. 
$primary_sum   = ceil($dni / 2);

// Then just subtract the $primary_sum from $dni
// and you'll have your $secondary_sum.
$secondary_sum = $dni - $primary_sum;


// Here what I did is make an array with $dni number of keys.
// (Serves as your switch statement).
foreach (array_fill(1, $dni, '') as $day_number => $x)
{
    // Follow the logic.
    if ($day_number <= $primary_sum)
    {
        // This is a little trick but works like a charm.
        $sum1 += ${"day{$day_number}"}; // It's basically $day1... and on.
    }
    else if ($day_number > $primary_sum)
    {
        // This is a little trick but works like a charm.
        $sum2 += ${"day{$day_number}"};
    }
}

// Number of integers in first sum (sum1)
var_dump($primary_sum);

// Number of integers in second sum (sum2)
var_dump($secondary_sum);

// The total sum of sum1 (pretty obvious).
var_dump($sum1);

// The total sum of sum2 (pretty obvious).
var_dump($sum2);
```

You can paste that code in [phpsandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/) and see it in action.